# C++ - How can I access the elements of pairs pushed in a vector via Variadic template

Tags: c++, class, vector, variadic-templates, std-pair

I need to call the C class object like this -

```
int main()
{
  C<Pair<"x", A<int>>, Pair<"y", A<double>>, Pair<"z", B<int>>> c1;
  C<Pair<"x", A<int>>, Pair<"y", A<double>>> c2;
}
```

I have this code so far -

```
template <typename X>
class A
{
  .....
};

template <typename Y>
class B
{
  .....
};

template <typename S, typename T>
struct Pair // wrap a generic type
{
  pair<S,T> p;

}

template <typename... P>
class C
{
  tuple<Pair*...> v; // every time the class and type will differ??
  public:

  void func()
  {
    v.push_back(//all P in sequence);
    //access the 1st and 2nd element of each pair in vector
  }
  
};
```

How can I push all P in sequence and then access the elements of each pair in class C?

If there is a fault in the above approach, then what other way I can use to be able call class C object like mentioned above?

Comment: `Pair` is not a tupe. There is no such thing as `vector<Pair*>`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Pair is the name of the structure so it has to have Pair* type data. I think it should be vector<P*>

Comment: @ManasviGoyal that cannot work. each `Pair` has a different type. They cannot be stored in a vector. You may need type erasure for this. Can i ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox So can I use a tuple here instead?

Comment: No, because each tuple has different types and is therefore itself a different type. A vector cannot store different types. You could use a `std::variant`.

Comment: "Pair is the name of the structure" No it is not. It is the name of the *template*. A template is not a structure. The difference between a structure and a template is the the same as difference between a cookie and a cookie cutter. You don't eat a cookie cutter.